# $X$ first-order stochastic dominates (FSD) $Y$. Does this imply $X-\frac{1}{X}$ FSD $Y-\frac{1}{Y}$?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ first-order stochastic dominates (FSD) $Y$, where $X>0$ and $Y>0$.

Then it is straightforward to see $-\frac{1}{X}$ FSD $-\frac{1}{Y}$.
How about the sum of these two?

In other words, does $X-\frac{1}{X}$ first-order stochastically dominate $Y-\frac{1}{Y}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x) = x-\frac{1}{x}$ is strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$, since $f'(x) = 1+\frac{1}{x^2}$ is positive. Let $f^{-1} : \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ denote its inverse. Then for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$\mathbb{P}(f(X) \geq x) = \mathbb{P}\left(X \geq f^{-1}(x)\right) \stackrel{\text{(FSD)}}{\geq} \mathbb{P}\left(Y \geq f^{-1}(x)\right) = \mathbb{P}(f(Y) \geq x). $$

So $f(X)$ [first-order stochastically dominates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#First-order) $f(Y)$.